# Rails 5.1.4 fields_for for multiple objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an `Author` and `Book` model. An Author can have many `Book`, but a Book can only have one `Author`.

During the creation of a new `Author`, how do I add a "New Book" button which will add a fields_for for the `Author` form? I want to be able to add more than one `Book`. So far, the [solution](https://www.theodinproject.com/courses/ruby-on-rails/lessons/advanced-forms) that I have found is just to add a fixed number of fields_for, like this:

```
<%= form_with(model: author, local: true) do |form| %>
...
    <% 5.times do %>
        <%= form.fields_for :books do |books| %>
        ...
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
...
<% end %>
```

I do not want it to be like this, what if the author has more than 5 books? I want to be able to add books dynamically. Any solutions?

Comment: Please check my answer, let me know if it is working or not

Comment: You can use `link_to_add` feature from https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form#usage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you fine with adding a new dependency, there's [cacoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) gem, which allows you easier handle nested forms.

It's an additional dependency, but the code for adding a new associated record is simple as:

```
<%= form_for author do |f| %>
  ...
  <%= f.fields_for :books do |book| %>
    <%= render 'book_fields', f: book %>
    <%= link_to_add_association 'add book', f, :books %>
  <%end%>
```

Answer (score 1):

author.rb

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :books,
    :allow_destroy => true,
    :reject_if     => :all_blank
```

In your view file

```
<div class="bank_account_details">
  <%= f.fields_for :bank_account_details do |builder| %>
    <p>
    Book: <%= builder.text_field :name %>
          <%= builder.check_box :_destroy %>
          <%= builder.label :_destroy, "Remove Book" %>
    </p>
  <% end %>
<div>
<%= link_to_add_fields "Add Book", f ,:books %>
```

In your controller add parameters

```
params.require(:author).permit(:name, books_attributes: [:id, :name, :_destroy])
```

Comment: This looks really incomplete. Afaik `link_to_add_fields` method does not exist in rails. How does the the `link_to_add_fields` know what to render? Which gem do you use to provide this functionality?